# basic jquery autocomplete with remote data source --how?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

What is the proper way to get autocomplete working with remote data?  I read the document at

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

and ran the example code.  The example  worked just fine for local data stored in a JS array, but when I used a remote URL, it doesn't work.  I see the autocomplete HTTP request being generated, and I can see my local web server responding with the correct data.  But the autocomplete info does not pop up.

Here is my .html code, it is only different by 2 lines from the example in the jquery documentation:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/main.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     url = "http://localhost:8000/autocomplete/"
     $("#example").autocomplete(url);
  });
  </script>

   </head>
   <body>
     API Reference: <input id="example" /> (try "C" or "E")
   </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything else needed in the .htm file?  Should I change the data format returned by the server?  Currently when I type "fr" into the text box, my server returns this:

```
["fractal","FRACTAL","fractalzebra","frad","Fraet",]
```

I am just trying to display a simple list of strings, I don't need to include any additional data in the server response unless it turns out to be required by jquery.

Thanks in advance, this problem has really been stumping me.

-Travis

Comment: Looks like the JSON you are returning is invalid. Try taking that last comma off there. Does it work then?

Comment: I tired removing the comma, it didn't help.  See my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're also not running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue which, prior to jQuery 1.5, required all different origin domain ajax calls to be jsonp, and now are implementable with crossDomain:true. As far as the Autocomplete plugin goes, I'm not aware how it fetches the data so this might not be applicable, but what you said about the local version working and the remote data not made me think of this immediately.

Comment: Hmm, I think by local he means locally defined in the javascript file. He's still fetching the 'remote' data from his local server. I don't believe he is running into cross domain problems.

Comment: Thanks AlienWebGuy.  Marc has it right, the local data is an array defined in the javascript section of the .html file, and the 'remote' data is generated by a server running on localhost.

Comment: This seems to have been the problem after all.  I had been testing in my browser by opening a .html file on my filesystem.  When I hosted the .html file on the web server and loaded it from there, auto-complete worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the server should return a valid JSON string and the last entry is invalid because it does not contain quotes. I think you should do a simple test by just returning a simple set of data, not something generated with your backend code.

```
["fractal","FRACTAL","fractalzebra","frad","Fraet",]
```

Should be

```
["fractal","FRACTAL","fractalzebra","frad","Fraet"]
```

Example of my testing idea would been to just do a test with a html file containing ["test1,"test2"]. Call this file in your URL parameter and see. If it works than it was your generated JSON string that contain an error.

Comment: Yup, exactly what I suggested.

Comment: @mark
@daok

I made this change but it had no effect.  When I use a locally-defined javascript array, these both work:
'code'
    ["fractal","FRACTAL","fractalzebra","frad","Fraet",]

and

    ["fractal","FRACTAL","fractalzebra","frad","Fraet"]

When getting the same data from my server, neither format causes the autocomplete popup to display.

Comment: One thing I noticed when monitoring the page with firebug is that the resource 'jquery.dimensions.js' was failing to load, with the server returning a 404.  This did not stop the local data from rendering properly in the autocomplete popup, but could it perhaps be an issue here?  Would it be better to use a specific released version of jquery rather that the code that's in the trunk branch as suggested in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I set it up working on my local. Try the following:

test.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     url = "http://localhost/test-data.php"
     $("#example").autocomplete({
         source: url
     });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 API Reference: <input id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

test-data.php

```
["test", "tooth", "no way", "blah"]
```

The differences here are the format of the options you're giving the autocomplete function. In addition, just to make sure you're getting them correctly, I'm loading the two libraries from google. Note that you'll also need the jquery ui css files. This should work for testing though.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I think loading the .js files from google is a good idea.  Unfortunately with your example code I'm having the same result -- I can get local javascript array data to pop up, but data returned from the server does not pop up.  Are you setting any particular content-type, or other headers in your HTTP response?

Comment: Nope that is literally all there is to it. Just those two files. If you're on port 8000 make sure you updated the url in my example. Do you at least see the requests being fired off in your firebug console when you type in the autocomplete box? If so, what does the response look like?

Comment: Firebug shows what seems to be a correct HTTP request/response sequence every time a letter is typed into the input field. For test purposes I'm having my server return an exact copy of your array above.  Do you have links to the specific .css file you are using?  I'm not particularly hopeful that's a solution, but I'm close to being out of ideas here.